# separation distance of random walk on finite groups

Tags: group-theory, probability-theory, random-walk

Given a random walk on a finite group $(G,S,P)$. Separation distance $s_k$ is defined by the formula $$s_k=|G|\times\max_{ g \in G}\left(\frac{1}{|G|}-Q^k(g)\right).$$

We call an element $\hat{g}_k$ "$k$-minimal" if the probability distribution $Q^k$ on a group $G$ has a minimum value at $\hat{g}_k$. We define a minimal sequence to be a sequence $(\hat{g}_1, \hat{g}_2,...)$ to be any sequence of $k$-minimal elements for each $k>0$.

I don't understand why :

If we have a minimal sequence $(\hat{g}_1, \hat{g}_2,...)$. By definition of the separation distance we have $$s_k=1-|G|*Q^k(\hat{g_k})$$

[image]

Comment: Where is the quote from? Also, please avoid pictures of text by typing them up in $\LaTeX$. This is so that the question is more easily found than otherwise; besides, some devices do not render pictures. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Just reading prof Igor Pak's phd thesis.

Comment: Ok I understand it now, you just write 1 as $\frac{|G|}{|G|}$ and factor the $|G|$ out and then that is it.